# Destructuring assignment and default values

Tags: coffeescript

Coffescript supports default arguments for functions and destructuring assignments. Is there any way to combine those features?

Destructuring assignment for agruments

```
({name, age}) ->
    "#{name} is #{age} years old?"
```

Default argument value

```
(name, age = 18) ->
    "#{name} is #{age} years old?"
```

Something like

```
({name, age = 18}) -> #syntax error
    "#{name} is #{age} years old?"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not supported, it is an open issue here: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/1558. ES6 *will* support destructuring with defaults everywhere, but CS, alas no.

Seems like the closest you can get is to initialize on separate lines:

```
f = ({a, b})->
  b ?= 2
  console.log {a: a, b:b}
```

This tempting (but ugly) syntax was 'discouraged', and does not even work for me currently on recent versions of coffeescript, but I suppose YMMV.

```
f = ({a, b}, b=2)->
  console.log {a: a, b:b}
```